# StackExchange Redis Search on Collection

Tags: azure, redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

We are looking at using Redis hosted in Azure. Using the StackExchange nuget, our first usage case is a search against our customer base. This is initially about 10,000 customers but will grow over time.

The customer will be a specific search model, something like this:

```
    {
     "Id": 123,
     "Name": "Bob Smith",
     "Age": 72,
     "Postcode": "AB123EF",
     "Email": "bobsmith@anon.com",
     "Telephones": [
        "07710123456", 
        "01453123456"
      ]
    }
```

My understanding is that you should avoid entering large blob objects into Redis, so storing the list as one object is not a great idea. So we have used the List* functions to store each item under a key and serializing the data.

Initial work looks something like this:

```
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var customer in customers)
    {
     tasks.Add(db.ListLeftPushAsync(_key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer)));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(true);
```

This all works as we expect, I'm sure there's some optimization, but seems ok.

That has fundamentally left us with the question of querying the information. I understand that Redis stores everything as a string, but I don't understand how to search the list, as it is a Redis object and not a string. So we can't use `ListRange(_key).Where(c => c.Contains("Bob"))` for example.

Please let me know if our approach is wrong on this or there is a method I am just missing.

Comment: Did you consider using RediSearch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm completely agree with what @GuyKorland said that you should use a mature product like [`RediSearch`](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/index.html), not to realize a custom search engine based on redis.

However, I'm very glad to simply introduce about how to implement a simple search engine by using the data structure of redis, just based on my knowledge for redis.

First, how to store a customer data like your sample customer into redis. You know, redis is a K-V database on memory, so you can flat store an object or a json data as a redis `Hash` structure with its key using the unique `Id` & a prefix, as below.

```
CUSTOM#123 => 
  Id => 123
  Name => Bob Smith
  Age => 72,
  Postcode => AB123EF
  Email => bobsmith@anon.com
  Telephones#0 => 07710123456
  Telephones#1 => 01453123456
```

Second, to build the indexes for all properties of the object class by using redis `List` or `Sorted Set` structure, as below.

For examples, using `List` for `Name` and `Age` properties. The idea is to use a prefix like `NAME` concat a `Name` value of a object like `Bob` with a symbol `#` to build a redis key and store the `Id` value as a redis `List` element.

```
\\ To build `NAME` index for all objects contains `Bob`, `Smith` and `Bob Smith` in the `Name` propertory
NAME#Bob => 123, ... 
NAME#Smith => 123, ...
NAME#Bob Smith => 123, ...
\\ Do the same operation above to build `AGE` index
AGE#72 => 123, ...
```

Finally, you can search `Bob` in the redis keys having the prefix `NAME#` by using command `GET NAME#Bob` to get the list of customer `Id` exactly or command `keys NAME#Bob*` to get the list of customer `Id` fuzzily, then you can continous to get these customer data contains the `Name` property with `Bob` value. If you want to sort the list of customer `Id`, you should use `Sorted Set` instead of `List` to sort the result of `Id` list.

I still recommended you should use a mature product based on redis, such as `RediSearch`, it will help you to fast realize your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The azure implementation does not support Redisearch out of the box, so if hosting it there we'd have to go down the docker route. However, another option is to host it in our own architecture.